# Using Maven with Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, maven-dependency-plugin

I just started working with maven and I am really new to this concept. I am using m2Eclipse plugin to work in maven. I use dependency to include the quartz library.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

and inside the guest/.m2/repository I can see the the corresponding library files.
But in code I cant import the quartz library. Its showing errors.

I can see that the maven repository is included in class path.

What is the reaon for this?
Also when I use Debug As > Maven Install

Its shows some log and in the end it says build successful

Whats Happening?

```
Error : import org.quartz cannot be resolved
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: To narrow down the problem, look at what the "Maven Dependencies" classpath container contains. Is the quartz library there? Does it contain the class you are trying to import?

Comment: @BeauGrantham edited with error details

Comment: @meriton its not just quartz I am also using another library called slf4j its also showing the same

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions, does it?

Comment: Maybe try Maven -> enable depedency management from the context menu if it's not enabled already

Comment: @Zach Just a hunch, but sometimes if you have an error in your POM XML's syntax, imports aren't resolved properly until you fix it. Also try to update your dependencies: right click on the project, Maven, update project configuration. My last advice is that you should probably check out the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org) and start with CLI instead of m2eclipse to get a good understanding on _what's going on_.

Comment: @meriton yes the librarie are there quartz library is inside Repository>org>quartz-scheduler>quartz>

Comment: @KohányiRóbert thanks a lot. It worked when I udated project configuration :)

Comment: can you run `mvn help:effective-pom` and share all of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a *hunch*, but sometimes if you have an error in your *pom.xml's* syntax, imports aren't resolved properly until you fix it.

Also try to update your dependencies: right click on the project, Maven, update project configuration.

My last advice is that you should probably check out the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org) and start with CLI instead of m2eclipse to get a good understanding on *what's going on*.

<sub>(I've extracted my comment as answer—if that's okay—so that the OP could accept it as answer, maintaining a good accept rate, creating a win-win situation! :)</sub>